# Record URL including semicolon in which once removed works, where is it coming from?

Tags: dynamics-crm-2011, dynamics-crm, crm

I have a CRM workflow where I include a link in an email sent out from the process which is a shortcut to the custom entity it is focussed on.

The hyperlink in the email looks like the following:

http://myserver.com:1234/Test/userdefined/edit.aspx?etc=10011&id;edf6a969-c458-e211-ba79-005056950002

This page fails to load, giving an http exception.

I removed the semicolon from  "&id;=" and it then works!

My question is... where is this semicolon coming from and how do I get rid of it?

Thanks

Answer (score 2):

Figured it out...

I inserted the Record URL as a value in the email on its own, not as part of a hyperlink.

I fixed it by doing "Insert Hyperlink" and then filling in the name and value elements appropriately.

Hope it helps someone else!